# Does defining a DataSource bean automatically stop spring auto-config, even if the data source is not annotated with @Primary?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.auto-configuration.replacing) states that if you add your own `DataSource` bean, spring will not handle the Auto-configuration anymore.

Basically, I want to have two data sources in my project. I was thinking that I can explicitly config the second ds, and not annotate it with `@Primary`, and Spring will do the auto-config for the primary data source. After trying to do this without any success and reading the docs, it is still unclear to me what they really mean. Does declaring any bean of type `DataSource` stop the auto config, even if it's not the primary one? Or is the auto config stopped only if you annotate the bean with `@Primary` / leave it with the default name (which I believe is simply "dataSource"). I have manually configured the default data source so I know how to do that, but I want to know if it's really necessary.

Thanks, any help would be really appreciated, as I have been stuck on this one for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to seems clear to me. Emphasise is mine.

> Auto-configuration is non-invasive. At any point, you can start to define your own configuration to replace specific parts of the auto-configuration. For example, **if you add your own DataSource bean, the default embedded database support backs away**.

`@Primary` or the bean name is not mentioned at all, so I'm not sure why you would expect it to be relevant.

It even describes in the following paragraph how to run you application so you can see which autoconfigurations are applied and why (not).

> If you need to find out what auto-configuration is currently being applied, and why, start your application with the --debug switch. Doing so enables debug logs for a selection of core loggers and logs a conditions report to the console.